# CURL csv download retrieves different data to link download

Tags: c++, validation, curl

I am trying to download a csv file from the ASX, and running it through google chrome and the downloads works nicely. My problem arises when loading the data via CURL into a string in C++, the data looks different / has different rows.

Clicking this link downloads the csv with come company data for each code,  https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/directory/file?access_token=83ff96335c2d45a094df02a206a39ff4

and, in rows 5 & 6, the codes in the data is represented as

```
1ST
29M
```

Now if you try the following code in CURL, that should yield the same data, we get something different.

```
#include <string>
#include "curl/curl.h"

size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main()
{
    CURL* m_MyHandle;
    CURLcode m_Result;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    m_MyHandle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(m_MyHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "YOUR_USER_AGENT");
    curl_easy_setopt(m_MyHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_MyHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://asx.api.markitdigital.com/asx-research/1.0/companies/directory/file?access_token=83ff96335c2d45a094df02a206a39ff4");
    
    std::string codeNamesBuff;
    curl_easy_setopt(m_MyHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &codeNamesBuff);
    printf("%s", codeNamesBuff.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Checking the output of this code, in the corresponding lines, 5 & 6, the data there is different. Instead, there is a value of `1VG` in row 6. This also applies for more codes listed later in the data, however, it seems extremely weird to me that this is happening.

Comment: It is the server's random behavior, I downloaded the csv by Chrome several times, saw `"1VG","VICTORY GOLDFIELDS LIMITED",,"Materials",0` randomly

Comment: @shdxiang Is it consistent for you through chrome? Because downloading via chrome I never get `"1VG","VICTORY GOLDFIELDS LIMITED",,"Materials",0`, only through CURL.

Comment: No, downloaded 4 times, 3 of them include `"1VG","VICTORY GOLDFIELDS LIMITED",,"Materials",0`

Comment: How is that even possible if it is just downloading an existing file that seems so odd to me.

Comment: Maybe it is not a static file, it is assembled by the server dynamically when clients want to download it